# finding duplicate values from two sheets

Tags: excel

I have Excel two sheets
data like these....

```
sheet1:  2000, 3000, 4500, 300, 2000, 3000      
sheet 2: 300, 2000, 3000, 4550
```

i run the following code to highlight the values in both sheets with different colors, where value meets with criteria.
but problem is values of sheet1 all 2000, 3000 filled with colors, whereas sheet2 having 2000, 3000 only one time.
if compare with sheet 2 it contains values 2000, 3000 only one time
so sheet1 values first and second fill with colors, rest of values (last two values) should not be in color.

great thanks for solution.

```
Sub Dupranges()

Dim wr1 As Range, wr2 As Range, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range


Set wr1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("f1:f10")
Set wr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("g1:g10")


For Each Rng1 In wr1
    Rng1.Value = Rng1.Value
    For Each Rng2 In wr2
        If Rng1.Value = Rng2.Value Then 
            Rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
            Rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

MsgBox "Successfully completed"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got what you wanted, its not pretty but i have just started the vba.
You have to change the range back to yours

```
Sub format()

Dim wr1 As Range, wr2 As Range


Set wr1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a10")
Set wr2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1:a10")


For i = 1 To wr1.Count
check_value = wr1.Item(i)
For k = 1 To wr2.Count
    check_value2 = wr2.Item(k)
    If (check_value = check_value2) And (wr2.Item(k).Interior.ColorIndex = 33) And 
(wr1.Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43) Then
    Else
    If (check_value = check_value2) And (wr2.Item(k).Interior.ColorIndex <> 33) And 
(wr1.Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex <> 43) And (wr2.Item(k).Value > "") Then
    wr1.Item(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    wr2.Item(k).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
        Exit For
    End If
   End If
Next
Next


MsgBox "Successfully completed"

End Sub
```

Hopefully you find this usefully

Comment: it works fine, thanks for your support. but, i have 9000 rows in both sheets, so its take too much time... any solutions greatly appreciate...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly ok, but you can save time moving ranges to arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Sub showDupes(src As Range, tgt As Range)
    Dim c As Range, i As Long, srcVal
    Dim a As Variant, found As Boolean

    a = tgt.Value2   'store tgt into array for speed

    For Each c In src
        srcVal = c.Value2
        found = False
        For i = 1 To UBound(a)
            If a(i, 1) = srcVal Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If found Then
            'highlight in src
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
            'highlight in tgt
            tgt.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Sub showDupes_test()
    showDupes Sheet1.Range("B4").CurrentRegion, Sheet2.Range("b4").CurrentRegion
End Sub
```

Note that in this version, if tgt has local duplicates, only the first one will be highlighted.

Comment: great...thanks for your support , But i have 9000 rows in both sheets.  i would like to search data from sheet1 - F column and sheet2 G column. Sub showDupes_test()
    showDupes Sheet1.Range("f1:f9000").CurrentRegion, Sheet2.Range("g1:g9000").CurrentRegion
End Sub  and  tgt.cells(i, 7) and if a(i, 6) i adjust the code like these..

Comment: the adjustments not matching with my need. so please correct me... once again thanks for your work....